# adding dynamic content using javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, html, appendchild

I want the following functionality in my webpage :-

when the add button is clicked, an entire div should get appended to a span. To achieve this I have attempted the below, but it does not seem to be working. Please explain why and how can i get this done.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function add()
     {
        var details=document.getElementById('education');
        var eachDetail=document.getElementById('fdetails_edu_div');
        alert(details.getAttribute('id'));
        alert(eachDetail.getAttribute('id'));
        var x=details.appendChild(eachDetail);
        alert(x);
     }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="education">
<div id="fdetails_edu_div">
 <label>EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION
   <span class="small">Click on 'ADD' to add more qualifiaction details</span>
 </label>
 <button type="button" name="addqualifiaction" onclick="add()">ADD</button> 
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Degree
   <span class="small">School/Board</span>
 </label>
 <p>
   <input type="text" name="school_board" id="fdegree" size="30" maxlength="30" value="none"   class="fprjtit"/>
 </p>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Year
   <span class="small">Year of Passing</span>
 </label>
 <p>
   <input type="text" name="pass_year" id="fdegree" size="30" maxlength="30" value="none" class="fprjtit"/>
 </p>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Max Marks
   <span class="small">maximum marks</span>
 </label>
 <p>
   <input type="text" name="max_marks" id="fdegree" size="30" maxlength="30" value="none" class="fprjtit"/>
 </p>
</div>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

now when i click on the add button the div with the id "fdetails_edu_div" should get appended as a child, preferably to the bottom, of the span with the id "education".

What is wrong with the below and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Firstly, don't put a `<div>` inside a `<span>` as that's not valid HTML. Second, `fdetails_edu_div` is already a child of `education` in your markup - where would it go?

Comment: ok, so will it be ok if i replace the span tag with a div. A div inside a div is perfectly valid, right? And yes, fdetails_edu_div is a child on education. What i want is that clicking the add button should add more such divs to education.

Comment: Yep, `<div>` inside is fine. You need to create a clone of the node instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

Comment: clone seems to be a good option, but with clone, will it be possible to manage the names of the different tags inside the cloned elements. I mean, I need to handle the cloned elements on the server side as well. So for each of the tags i would want to give them a dynamically generated unique name, say name1, name2 etc. If I was appending elements i could manage this though Javascript. Will it possible here as well ?

Comment: Sure, once the cloned element is added to the DOM, you can query it and manipulate it in the usual way. Perhaps though to save some trouble you should look into something like Knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: thanks Graham.. all comments were great help. (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to clone the div with id `fdetails_edu_div`

Use the following code

```
var x = 1;

function add() {
    var container = document.getElementById('education');
    var detail = document.getElementById('fdetails_edu_div');
    var clone = detail.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "fdetails_edu_div" + x;
    x++;
    container.appendChild(clone);

}
```

Notice, I create a new id for the newly created div.

Also note, I have removed the `Add` button from within the div `fdetails_edu_div` and placed it outside (you don't want the add button to repeat, do you?)

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjNGP/)

Answer (score 0):

The usage of appendChild() is move an element from one element to another,[check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

Based on your code, you move the 'eachDetail' to 'details', but 'eachDetail' is already there. It works like you remove the 'eachDetail' and then add it again in the 'details', so nothing happens.

You can replace 'details' with another element, a new span.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 function add()
 {
    var arr = [];
    var n = 0;
    var details=document.getElementById('education');
    var eachDetail=document.getElementById('fdetails_edu_div');
    alert(details.getAttribute('id'));
    alert(eachDetail.getAttribute('id'));
    node = document.getElementById("fdetails_edu_div");
    while (node.firstChild) {
        arr[n++] = node.firstChild;
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        details.appendChild(arr[i]);
    }
    alert(eachDetail.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
 }
```

Above code first removes the child nodes of div with id fdetails_edu_div, saves them temporarily and later appends them to span with id education. You can check this with alert(eachDetail.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));